# Primary Tabs in Google

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

"Primary Tabs" is coming up as one of our top pages in Google and it takes users to the log in page. I'm not sure what "Primary Tabs" means. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I created a sitemap using XMLSiteMap module. Initially had allowed the menu items to be captured in the site map. I have since removed menu items, recreated and resubmitted the sitemap to Google and asked Google to re-crawl the home page but it still shows.

Our home page is set to the highest priority, followed by certain custom pages and content types.

https://fosterclub.com/sitemap.xml

Is "Primary Tabs" a Drupal thing or a Google thing and if it's a Drupal thing, where might this be coming from?

[image]

Google last cached our homepage today.
[image]

Edit: here is what is in the view/edit/etc. tabs, but Google wouldn't have access to these.
[image]

Comment: How long ago did you resubmit the sitemap?  Has Google crawled the new sitemap?  You can check this kind of thing in Google Search Console.  It also depends on what priorities you set in the sitemap.  You'll need to post more details about how exactly you configured the sitemap for us to help you.

Comment: I don't think Google uses the sitemap to generate site links, last time I checked (admittedly a while back) it was based on the navigation hierarchy that the engine inferred from crawling the site. "Primary tabs" is typically the heading, visible or not, that sits with the View/Edit/etc tabs (the `$tabs` var in page.tpl.php). That might be what Google are picking up, but quite why they're treating it as the title of a page is difficult to say